# Google Analytics/Adwords data in SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2016

I have a google analytics account and would like to extract the data from this into a SQL server database using SSIS - does anyone know of a free way of doing this?

I have used the Kingsway soft SSIS productivity pack trial and this works OK but my trial has run out now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the execute process task to execute a powershell script that retrieves data from 
 the Google Analytics API. (Something like this: https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/eb95ed53c7ae18273434ff6b4789dc7d)